# External CSS don't work

Tags: css, external

I have an external css file, linked in to the html. If i apply style for example a div class it Works, but when i apply style for html, body etc. it doesn't work. Why is that?

This is the CSS code:

```
 html {
        background: url(img/bc.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;

        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    }
```

This code only work, when i put a style tag into the html file.

And this is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you defining the CSS? We can't answer your question unless you tell us that.

Comment: Can you try putting your code in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? It's pretty difficult to diagnose your problem otherwise.

Comment: Hi @MGamer333, could you provide the HTML file as well as your file structure?  Then we might be able to better assist you.  Anish Sana recommended using jsfiddle, which would be very helpful.

Comment: try this code .  background: url(../img/bc.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
check the image if you have have a html file and folder css which holds the css file like the given image then you can add the css to html like the given link tag.

<
link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">

now you can write whatever css you want under the css/base.css file and you have to use the url directory property like

url("../image/image.png")

whick says that one level up and find the image directory and add image.png to this html document

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, but when I removed some of the letters from the link, it worked out.
Remove (css/) and let the (style.css) only be in the place, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the image url, for example consider the following directories:

- /img/bc.jpg
- /css/style.css
- index.html

, the `style.css` code is

```
html {
    background: url(../img/bc.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

add the following code to the header of the page e.g. `index.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
        background: url('https://www.bottega7.com/media/filer_public_thumbnails/filer_public/f5/98/f5986e4f-b733-4ab8-aa3b-0d474d257464/copertina_img-theme-park_v2.jpg__1200x700_q100_crop_subsampling-2_upscale.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;

        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
          <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also make sure you have the correct style.css and img path.
It is only in path problem and not others.